# Customization of error messages at chekout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to change the error messages displaying in checkout page.(Image attached for Default  error message)

**Image of Default error messages at checkout page**

[image]

Ex. I want to change error message **Billing First name is a required field** to  **First name can not be left blank**.

To achieve this at present i am using the following -

> First I removed the Billing keyword from the message.For this i used
> the following code in my function.php.

```
        function remove_billing_keyword_error( $error ) {
        if ( strpos( $error, 'Billing ' ) !== false ) {
            $error = str_replace("Billing ", "", $error);
        }
        return $error;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'remove_billing_keyword_error' );
```

**Output after remove_billing_keyword_error function -**

[image]

> After that I am using woocommerce_after_checkout_validation action hook for custom validation & error messages. But it is executing after the default validation  & both messages are displaying (image attached).

```
function woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation($fields, $validation_errors)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        error_log("User is logged in :: Callback Name woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation");
    }else{
        
           if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( 'Confirm email address cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    }
    return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation', 10, 2);
```

**Output -**

[image]

> Ex. For Email both messages *Email address is a required field* & *Confirm email address cannot be left blank* are showing.

Any Advice ?

**UPDATE 1**

As per @CBroe suggested [link](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/custom-checkout-validation.html), i modified my code & by this now i am able to modified the error message at checkout page. Following is my modified version of code -

```
function woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation($fields, $validation_errors)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        error_log("User is logged in :: Callback Name woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation");
    }else{
        
        // if any validation errors
    if( !empty( $validation_errors->get_error_codes() ) ) {
 
        // remove all of them
        foreach( $validation_errors->get_error_codes() as $code ) {
            $validation_errors->remove( $code );
        }
 
        // add our custom one
        //$validation_errors->add( 'validation', 'Please fill the fields!' );

        if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
            $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( 'First name cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
                $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( 'Last name cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        
        if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email'] ) ) {
            $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( 'Billing email address cannot be left blank.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        if ( $fields['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $fields['billing_email']  ) {
            error_log("Confirm Email - " . $fields['billing_email_cnfrm'] ."And User Email - " . $fields['billing_email']);
            $validation_errors->add( 'email_not_match_error', __( 'Chekcout Error Email not match! .', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        if ( $fields['user_password_again']  != $fields['account_password']  ) {
            error_log("Checkout Password Log Block Run");
            $validation_errors->add( 'password_not_match_error', __( 'Chekcout Error Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        error_log("User is Not logged in :: Callback Name woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation");
        
    }    

    }
    return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation', 100, 2);
```

> At this my point, my question is there any inbuilt mechanism for validate the mobile number,email,number etc in woocommerce or i need to write everything from scratch.

**UPDATE 2**

For custom validating the postcode i am using is_postcode() function. I am using this with woocommerce_after_checkout_validation action hook in function.php file. But i am getting Fatal error:

```
[29-Dec-2021 06:17:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_postcode() in D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\themes\ljschildtheme\functions.php:703
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation(Array, Object(WP_Error))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-checkout.php(887): do_action('woocommerce_aft...', Array, Object(WP_Error))
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-checkout.php(1161): WC_Checkout->validate_checkout(Array, Object(WP_Error))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-ajax.php(466): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): WC_AJAX::checkout('')
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-ajax.php(90): do_action('wc_ajax_checkou...')
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(303): WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax('')
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(false, Array)
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-includes\template-loader.php(13): do_action('template_redire...')
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\index.php(17): require('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#16 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\wpreg\wp-content\themes\ljschildtheme\functions.php on line 703
```

My postcode validation code -

```
    if ( empty( $_POST['billing_postcode'] )) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_postcode_error', __( 'Post code can not be left blank', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) && is_postcode( $_POST['billing_postcode'],  $_POST['billing_city']) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_postcode_country_error', __( 'Post code provided is invalid', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
```

> How can i add custom validations for postcode,phone & email in function.php
> if i want to customize the error messages in checkout page. I dont want to use filters to change the error text.

Any advice.

Comment: _"Ex. For Email both messages Email address is a required field & Confirm email address cannot be left blank are showing."_ - aren't those two different messages to begin with? The first one relating to the email input field, and the second one referring to the email _confirmation_ field ...?

Comment: Thanks CBroe for reply. I added ' Confirm email address cannot be left blank' in woocommerce_checkout_extra_validation call back function where i am checking billing email for empty and for isset and in this point both messages are displaying.  am i using wrong hook?

Comment: You will have to unset the already existing validation error message for that field in $validation_errors then. https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/custom-checkout-validation.html has some more details.

Comment: You can use jquery valdations too after unset aleady used validation and make it like the way you want
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify any text that "wrapped" by translation function __() using gettext hook. Like this:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translation, $text, $domain ){
if( $domain == 'woocommerce' ){
    if ( strpos($text, 'Billing First name is a required field') !== false ) {
        $translation =  str_replace('Billing First name is a required field', 'irst name can not be left blank.', $text);
    }
}   
return $translation;}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks Movs for reply. In checkout page there is 14+ required fields for billing & shipping address & i belief if we use filters to change the text this can increase the execution time of script.